# Is this a valid and sound argument?

Tags: philosophy-of-religion

ToE - Theory of Evolution

- P1. The ToE is absurd in every way & no sound honest case has been or
  can be made for it.
- P2. The Biblical explanation for life on earth IS the only sound
  explanation that fits the available evidence.
- Cl. The ONLY sane, honest, & sound case for life on earth can be made
  from a biblical perspective--every other explanation does NOT fit the
  facts sufficiently.

The entire argument seems muddled, but it seems to be saying:

- P1. ToE has not been sufficiently established
- P2. The Bible offers the only sound explanation given the evidence
- Cl. The Bible offers the only sound explanation given the evidence

It seems to me that P2 and C1 are the same, so it is not even a valid structure let alone a sound argument.

Thoughts?

Comment: An argument that assumes its own conclusion *is* valid, in the formal sense of logical validity. But of course any argument of this form is question begging.

Comment: ToE typically means Theory of Everything, while the Theory of Evolution is generally just referenced as Evolution, at least where context (like here) implies it.

Comment: Please make explicit in the title what the question is about. We have about a thousand "is this argument sound/valid?" questions. Also, I think "theory of evolution" and "biblical explanation" were mixed in the premises.

Answer (score 1):

There's a huge difference between P1 and "has not been sufficiently established". Of course P1 is three total nonsense claimed. P2 is wrong, because P1 fits the available evidence much better than P2.

And Q1 doesn't follow from P1 and P2, since there are plenty of other possible explanations. For example a very clever experiment by technologically slightly advanced aliens.